# Correct way to set HTTP referrers in "Accept requests from these HTTP referrers" field in google developer console

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, api-key

I need to secure my paid google map API key in google developer console.
I had try this in 'Credentials' tab, in api key settings.
Field label 'Accept requests from these HTTP referrers ...'.

If I'm right, this `*.dev2.urelay.xyz/*` must be useful for this URL - https://dev2.urelay.xyz/

But it doesn't work for me, I got this error in my console

```
Google Maps API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
```

`Your site URL to be authorized: https://dev2.urelay.xyz/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*.dev2.urelay.xyz/*` doesn't match `https://dev2.urelay.xyz/` because it requires a period (`.`) that isn't in that URL.

`dev2.urelay.xyz/*` would match it.  You only need the form `*.dev2.urelay.xyz/*` if you have a subdomain of dev2 that needs to host a map (like `https://www.dev2.urelay.xyz/`)

Comment: Great answer.  Just to clarify, I want to refer anything from my own website.  So http or https www or non www and any other subdomain.  So I should do `*mywebsite.com/*` right?